# Default SMTP functionality if one of multiple addresses is invalid

Tags: smtp

Although this is effectively a programming question, my gut feeling is that subject is more suited to this site.  However, if you feel it is better suited to Stackoverflow, please let me know and I'll ask it there instead.

Is there default functionality (or recognised standards) across SMTP relays as how they deal with a single email that has multiple addresses, where one or more of the address is invalid?

In my testing it appears that if the SMTP detects an invalid address (normally because there is no corresponding address in the corporate SMTP system I'm connecting to) then the entire email fails - nobody on the email receives it.

Can anybody confirm if this is standard functionality?

Or is it something that can be configured at an individual SMTP level?

Or is it down to the individual SMTP vendor to decide how it deals with emails where one or more addresses are invalid?

Is it ever possible that the "other" recipients would still get the email?

Notes...

- I am a programmer, not a network administrator, so I have literally no experience of setting up or configuring SMTP relays.  But I need to know how to handle those errors in my code should the SMTP I'm connected to come back with an issue.
- This is not specific to a particular SMTP vendor, as my application must run against any SMTP relay that our client desires.

Comment: Surprised by the close vote - although this is about development, the question is more about the fundamental standards of SMTP. I wonder if the close voter actually read the question, or just the first statement

Comment: Explanation of Internet protocols has historically been mostly on topic here, so I'm a bit surprised by that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have one email with multiple receivers where one is invalid, the mail server tries to send the email until it encounters the email address with the error. Then it usually sends a non-delivery notification to the sender, and it stops to process the email further.

That means you basically can't know who received the email and who didn't. The order of the email addresses that it tries to send the email to, is not guaranteed. It might take the order of the addresses in the email, or use some entirely different order.

I know this because I used to be responsible for investigating delivery issues for the biggest provider in my country.

Here is what the mail sever basically does:

1. Make a list of all receivers (in an unknown order)
2. Try to send email to each receiver individually
3. It encounters the receiver with delivery issues
4. It usually sends a non-delivery message to the sender.
5. It usually stops sending the message to the remaining receivers.

There might be some mail servers that are configured differently or have different default behavior.

This is one of the mail reasons why you have to use newsletter software for sending out newsletters. They send each email individually to avoid this issue.

Delivery issues can have many reasons. Some of them are:

- invalid email syntax
- invalid user name (name before @ symbol)
- invalid hostn name
- mailbox is full
- invalid MX records (or A record if MX is not present)
- blocked sender email
- sender server is blocked
- email is recognised as spam
- recever mail server is unavailable
- misconfigured gray listing on sender mail server

Some reasons for delays are

- sender mail server has too many emails in the queue
- recever mail server temporary unavailable (e.g. too much traffic, outage)
- gray listing is used and the sender server hasn't sent email to the receiver server for a while

Some errors only occur, after the mail server has tried to send an email. Therefore, it cannot know whether the email can be delivered before it tries. That means there is basically no way a mail server can guarantee it can stop the entire delivery before it reaches the invalid receiver.

**Conclusion:** The right way to send emails is to always send individual emails to each email address. (That's how newsletter software does it.)

Comment: Thank you - that's very useful... and pretty much confirms what I thought.  That there is simply no point doing single emails to multiple people.

Answer (score 1):

An email may be sent to any number of recipients. If it cannot be delivered to a single address, all other addresses will still receive the message. The sender will (usually) receive one or more nondelivery notifications showing the addresses that failed and giving the reason for the failure. (A third party provider such as Sendgrid might not send NDR messages via email but show this in a web based dashboard or provide it via API instead.)

RFC 5321 specifies that you are expected to repeat the RCPT command any number of times. In practice, you will connect to the mail server for a given domain, and then attempt to deliver to every address within that domain, by sending one MAIL command, multiple RCPT commands, then DATA. If an RCPT gives an error, you log it and continue. Then after all the addresses in all the domains are attempted, you send back an NDR to the sender with the failed addresses and reasons. Note that you have to queue and try again for a 4xx error. Your best bet as a programmer is not to try to implement SMTP yourself but to just send the mail to an existing SMTP server set up as a relay that already can handle everything for you.

Comment: Thanks @Michael - I've obviously not made myself clear. I am **not** writing an SMTP relay... my software is sending emails via SMTP, and I'm trying to work out how I should handle the situation of a single email to multiple recipients where one or more of them is classed as invalid as the SMTP

Comment: It's disappointing to read that *If it cannot be delivered to a single address, all other addresses will still receive the message* - from my testing using an SMTP that rejects based on a lack of associated account, the other valid email address did **not** receive the email, which led me to believe that as standard **no** recipients would receive it.  If you're saying that as standard SMTP relays should still send to valid addresses, that makes my life increasing difficult

Comment: If you're talking SMTP, you're an MTA and need to behave like one, with all the weird corner cases that implies.

Comment: ok, @womble - and where can I find documentation on how *to behave like one*? Where is it written exactly what situations can arise, and how I deal with them?  (Sorry for the delay in replying, but as you didn't tag me it was only by chance that I saw your comment)

Comment: @freefaller Mostly in the RFCs. But really, don't do this. Stop even thinking about it. You do not want to implement a whole SMTP server just to send some messages. That's a multi-year project and full of nightmares. Use an existing SMTP client library for your language to send the mail to an SMTP server and let it handle delivery.

Comment: @Michael - sorry, but repeat myself, I am **not writing an SMTP server**... I am writing software (MTA, as womble puts it) that is **sending emails via SMTP**.  My software is currently deployed to 50 different customers, all with different SMTP relays/configuration.  I am trying to work out how to deal with the situation of giving the SMTP an email with multiple recipients where one or more are invalid, and whether the valid ones still get the email.  Sorry, but I'm honestly not sure how much more clear I can be!

Comment: @freefaller An MTA _is_ an SMTP server! It's still not clear what you're doing. Is your program creating these emails itself? Does it receive them from somewhere else? Why are you even bothering with whether an email was or wasn't delivered?

Comment: Oh, then MTA is the wrong phrase, and I have obviously confused the issue. I am writing software (an ASP.Net web application) which sends email to people. I have a situation where I need to send a LOT of emails, which are currently being sent individually, but I'm hitting ASP.Net timeouts.  So as a solution I wanted to send a single email using all the addresses as BCC. However, I need to be able to report back to the user if the email was **sent** successfully - I have no interest in the delivery

Comment: Then just relay it to an existing SMTP server as I've advised several times. This is not difficult. If that server accepts it, then it was successfully sent.

Comment: OK - this is my last comment, because one of us simply can't grasp what appears to be a pretty simple question.  **I AM SENDING TO EXISTING SMTP SERVERS** - I'm sending them to approximately 50 of them.  What I am trying to do is work out **how to deal with the situation I've explained multiple times** when it doesn't appear that all SMTP work the same. I need to know if the one email will send to the valid addresses, or whether a single invalid address will stop the entire email going out.  I'm sorry to be so harsh, but I'm honestly struggling to work out how I'm not being clear

Comment: @freefaller I already answered that!

Comment: OK - but my testing show's that some SMTP's stop the entire email going out, which directly contradicts your answer.  What this 100% proves is that it is 100% pointless trying to write software to work like this, so will have to change my philosophy. I'm sorry for my tone, but I'm tired and shouldn't be working. Thank you for your time

Comment: @freefaller It's interesting if you found a misbehaving SMTP server. You should definitely try to get more information about that server if you can. But I recommend sleep first.